# Retrieve one out of every n records

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table containing thousands of records representing the temperature of a room in a certain moment. Up to now I have been rendering a client side graph of the temperature with JQuery. However, as the amount of records increases, I think it makes no sense to provide so much data to the view, if it is not going to be able to represent them all in a single graph.

I would like to know if there exists a single MySQL query that returns one out of every *n* records in the table. If so, I think I could get a representative sample of the temperatures measured during a certain lapse of time.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: add table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temperature` (
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Node identifier',
  `temperature` float unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Temperature in Celsius degrees',
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unix timestamp of the temperature record',
  PRIMARY KEY (`nid`,`timestamp`)
```

)

Comment: could you describe your table?

Comment: How should it select those records? If it's random, you can use `ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT x`, where `x` is `COUNT(*)/n`.

Comment: @bustikiller check my edit, contains your columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this, where the subquery is your query, and you add a row number to it:

```
SET @rows=0;
SELECT * from(
   SELECT @rows:=@rows+1 AS rowNumber,nid,temperature,`timestamp`
   FROM temperature
) yourQuery
WHERE MOD(rowNumber, 5)=0
```

The mod would choose every 5th row: The 5 here is your `n`. so 5th row, then 10th, 15th etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what your asking but you have multiple options

1. You can limit your results to n (n representing the amount of temperatures you want to display)

just a simple query with the limit in the end:

```
select * from tablename limit 1000
```

2. You could use a time/date restraint so you display only the results of the last n days.

Here is an example that uses date functions. The following query selects all rows with a date_col value from within the last 30 days:

```
mysql> SELECT something FROM tbl_name
    -> WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= date_col;
```

3. You could select an average temperature of a certain period, the shorter the period the more results you'll get. You can group by date, yearweek, month etc. to "create the periods"